# How would I set the value of '0xA5' as the first 5 bytes of my string "Now the Message is: "?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, 32-bit, memset

Currently my output looks like this:

[image]

But I'd like to replace the first 5 bytes of the string "The end is near!" with 'A5' at the end of my x_memset function following the statement "Now the message is: ".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>


void printBytes(char *data, int length)
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        if ((x & 0xF) == 0) printf("\n");
        printf("%02X ", (unsigned char)data[x]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return;
} // printBytes

void x_memset(void *destination, unsigned char value, int nCount,char *str) {

    __asm {
            mov eax, 16; push the length
            push eax
            mov eax, 0x41; push the value
            push eax
            lea eax, str; push the address of string
            push eax
            call inline_memset
            add esp, 12
            jmp EXIT
        inline_memset :
            mov ecx, [nCount]
            mov edi, [destination]
            mov al, [value]
            mov ebx, ecx
    //      shr ecx, 2
    //      and ebx, 3
    //      rep stosd
    //      mov ecx, ebx
    //      rep stosb
        EXIT:

    }
    printf("\nNow the message is : %s\n", str);
    printBytes(str, strlen(str));

    return;

} // end function

int main()
{
    char string[] = "The end is near!"; // this is 16 bytes + null
    printf("The message is : %s\n", string);
    printBytes(string,strlen(string));

    x_memset(0x1000,0xA5,5,string);
    //puts(string);
    //fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I greatly appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: Somebody commented out part of your code. Is that why it does not work?

Comment: Oh no, I did that while stepping through the code during debugging.

Comment: And now it does not work anymore? Because you commented out that piece of code that should do what you describe?

Comment: The obvious way to that specific 5-byte memset is `mov dword [mem], 0xa5a5a5a5` then a 1-byte store to `[mem+4]` of the last byte.  Look at how a compiler will inline memset in a function that calls it on a `char*`.

Comment: `lea eax, str` loads eax with the address of the pointer. You want `mov eax, str` which loads the value of the pointer, which is the address of the string.

Comment: @duckyPluck Please post the code that actually causes the problem you describe without any edits or commented out sections.